# JavaFX List View - Get currently selected item's index?

Tags: listview, javafx

I'm trying to implement a feature and I need the index number of the currently selected item in the list view. So if it's 4th on the list I need a method that will return 3 because I need to edit the corresponding object in an ArrayList.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answered the question; it will help others find it.